# Error: Assigning to an array from an initializer list; code working on ubuntu 10.04 but not on 14.04

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, initializer

I would be very happy if someone here could point me in the right direction regarding my issue.

I have read multiple posts about this matter on this and some other forums, but to no avail.

I work under Ubuntu 14.04 in Qt Creator 3.2.1 with C++. The code is large and old and it compiles on some other, older computer under Ubuntu 10.04 with no problems.

The error that I get is "Assigning to an array from an initializer list".

The code is like this:

```
MapOut =
{
    {0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0},{7,0},
    {0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,1},{7,1},
    {0,2},{1,2},{2,2},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{6,2},{7,2},
    {0,3},{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{4,3},{5,3},{6,3},{7,3},
    {0,4},{1,4},{2,4},{3,4},{4,4},{5,4},{6,4},{7,4},
    {0,5},{1,5},{2,5},{3,5},{4,5},{5,5},{6,5},{7,5},
    {0,6},{1,6},{2,6},{3,6},{4,6},{5,6},{6,6},{7,6},
    {0,7},{1,7},{2,7},{3,7},{4,7},{5,7},{6,7},{7,7},
    {0,8},{1,8},{2,8},{3,8},{4,8},{5,8},{6,8},{7,8},
    {0,9},{1,9},{2,9},{3,9},{4,9},{5,9},{6,9},{7,9},
    {0,10},{1,10},{2,10},{3,10},{4,10},{5,10},{6,10},{7,10},
    {0,11},{1,11},{2,11},{3,11},{4,11},{5,11},{6,11},{7,11},
    {0,12},{1,12},{2,12},{3,12},{4,12},{5,12},{6,12},{7,12},
    {0,13},{1,13},{2,13},{3,13},{4,13},{5,13},{6,13},{7,13},
    {0,14},{1,14},{2,14},{3,14},{4,14},{5,14},{6,14},{7,14},
    {0,15},{1,15},{2,15},{3,15},{4,15},{5,15},{6,15},{7,15},
    {0,16},{1,16},{2,16},{3,16},{4,16},{5,16},{6,16},{7,16},
    {0,17},{1,17},{2,17},{3,17},{4,17},{5,17},{6,17},{7,17},
    {0,18},{1,18},{2,18},{3,18},{4,18},{5,18},{6,18},{7,18},
    {0,19},{1,19},{2,19},{3,19},{4,19},{5,19},{6,19},{7,19},
    {0,20},{1,20},{2,20},{3,20},{4,20},{5,20},{6,20},{7,20},
    {0,21},{1,21},{2,21},{3,21},{4,21},{5,21},{6,21},{7,21},
    {0,22},{1,22},{2,22},{3,22},{4,22},{5,22},{6,22},{7,22},
    {0,23},{1,23},{2,23},{3,23},{4,23},{5,23},{6,23},{7,23}
};
```

Pretty large array... 36x8...
And if I do this:

```
static int MapOut[] =
{
    {0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0},{7,0},
    {0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,1},{7,1},
    {0,2},{1,2},{2,2},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{6,2},{7,2},
    {0,3},{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{4,3},{5,3},{6,3},{7,3},
    {0,4},{1,4},{2,4},{3,4},{4,4},{5,4},{6,4},{7,4},
    {0,5},{1,5},{2,5},{3,5},{4,5},{5,5},{6,5},{7,5},
    {0,6},{1,6},{2,6},{3,6},{4,6},{5,6},{6,6},{7,6},
    {0,7},{1,7},{2,7},{3,7},{4,7},{5,7},{6,7},{7,7},
    {0,8},{1,8},{2,8},{3,8},{4,8},{5,8},{6,8},{7,8},
    {0,9},{1,9},{2,9},{3,9},{4,9},{5,9},{6,9},{7,9},
    {0,10},{1,10},{2,10},{3,10},{4,10},{5,10},{6,10},{7,10},
    {0,11},{1,11},{2,11},{3,11},{4,11},{5,11},{6,11},{7,11},
    {0,12},{1,12},{2,12},{3,12},{4,12},{5,12},{6,12},{7,12},
    {0,13},{1,13},{2,13},{3,13},{4,13},{5,13},{6,13},{7,13},
    {0,14},{1,14},{2,14},{3,14},{4,14},{5,14},{6,14},{7,14},
    {0,15},{1,15},{2,15},{3,15},{4,15},{5,15},{6,15},{7,15},
    {0,16},{1,16},{2,16},{3,16},{4,16},{5,16},{6,16},{7,16},
    {0,17},{1,17},{2,17},{3,17},{4,17},{5,17},{6,17},{7,17},
    {0,18},{1,18},{2,18},{3,18},{4,18},{5,18},{6,18},{7,18},
    {0,19},{1,19},{2,19},{3,19},{4,19},{5,19},{6,19},{7,19},
    {0,20},{1,20},{2,20},{3,20},{4,20},{5,20},{6,20},{7,20},
    {0,21},{1,21},{2,21},{3,21},{4,21},{5,21},{6,21},{7,21},
    {0,22},{1,22},{2,22},{3,22},{4,22},{5,22},{6,22},{7,22},
    {0,23},{1,23},{2,23},{3,23},{4,23},{5,23},{6,23},{7,23}
};
```

the error is `"braces around scalar initializer for type 'int' "`.

I've had no luck getting over this problem so far...
Any help would be much appreciated... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is '`' character a typo or you use it in your code as well?

Comment: Sorry, It's a typo, It's my first post here, so I had some trouble with separating code from text. It seemed to me like those special signs helped with formatting... Silly me... :)

Comment: Approved the correction, no typos anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an array of integers, you have an array of *arrays* of integers. So you need to declare it as such:

```
static int MapOut[][2] = { ... };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I understand it is an array of arrays, just wasn't too sure about how to tell it to the computer :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

First of all arrays have no the assignment operator. So you may not write for example

```
MapOut = { /*...*/ };
```

Also I have not understood how `36x8` is related with the code snippet you showed.

Do you mean a two dimensional array?

In any case your initialization of the array is incorrect.

Maybe you want to have an array of pairs of integers and to be able to assign it after its definition. If so then you shpuld use standard class `std::array`

For example

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 36 * 8> a = { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, /*...*/ };
```

Comment: 288 pairs to be exact... So, 288 cells with 2 elements, but I obviously missed the point. Thank you for your response! I'll be more precise in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's your compiler.

The above 2nd example (ignoring the typos) compiles in c with warnings but fails in c++. Tried
http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php 
and http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php

You might have used an older C++ compiler that accepts the above - couldn't find a good selection of old compilers only.

Obviously as others point out, the code is buggy, but I'm just answering to the fact that it doesn't compile anymore while it used to.